# Fading values general function/procedure

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-xe3

I am after a general function/procedure that would calculate me fade times and values based on data provided, something like this:

I have byte values saved in a byte array: these are the *start values*. Then I have some memorized values in some other array: these are to be the *new values*. Then I have time to be provided, which is time needed a *start value* to get to *new value*.

I need to get updates on the values each time they change (up to 0.1 seconds accurate). I know that if value *A* changes for 10 and value *B* changes for 100 in the same time, let's say 1 second, I'll get value *A* updated 10 times, while value *B* will be updated 100 times.
So far I have been planning on using a timer, with interval let's say 50ms, which would constantly be calculating the difference based on the value of the change and the time needed, something like: `change step := (Difference between start and new value  / {divided by} (fade time / timer interval) )`.

But given the fact that value changes are different, fade times as well, and that I could execute another value fading before the first fading has ended, is making all of this confusing and difficult for me.

So, what I would need is an option to, let's say, given values at index 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 to be changed to their new values in 30 seconds, then at some point somewhere in between I could order the values at index 11, 13 and 17 to change to their new values in 9 seconds, etc...

Also, in case that value *A* would have a fading towards value *B* in progress, and another fade from *A* to *C* would be ordered, I would like it to be added to a queue list, to be executed right after the first fade is finished. And at that time, the *B* value from the first command would become the *A* value in the second command. This is due to these facts: The *A* in the example above should always be read at the very moment of the fade start. This way, it is a starting value no matter what was done before the fade or between the fade command and fade execution. Therefore, I could set Fade1 to *Current -> B @ 10s* and queue a Fade2 for *Current -> C @ 10s*, whereas the *Current* in the second case is actually value otherwise saved as *B*, and let's assume the *Current* in Fade1 is same as value saved as *C*. This way the value would be in a loopback, changing every 10 seconds. So basically, the command for adding a fade should only have something like *SetNewFade: Dest:=B; Time:=10;*.

So I could add *->B@10s*, *->C@10s*, *->B@10s*, *->C@10s*, and it would just loop from *B* to *C* and backwards until queue list is empty. I hope I managed to make this clear enough for you to understand. I really can't describe better what I need to achieve.

Also, as all of the fades would be provided in a Listbox, I would like to be able to delete fades in the queue as desired. But, if the currently running fade is deleted, the value should *jump* to a new value as if the fade would be already completed, and normally then start the new fade in queue list, if there's any.

How would that be the easiest to create? Is using Timer with fixed interval a good idea? Would it cause any delays if a lot of values would be pending for fade? Is using dynamic arrays for values and times (and populating them on *StartFade* event and release them after fading is complete) a shot in the dark or a good guess?

Here an example which I hope makes it clearer:

```
A: array [0..20] of Byte;
B: array [0..20] of Byte;
C: array [0..20] of Byte;
Current: array [0..20] of Byte;
```

Button1 applies the *A* values to the *Current values*, Button2 applies the *B* values, and Button3 applies the *C* values, and so on...

So I set time in an Edit box, let's say 5 seconds, and click on Button1. With that, I added the fade from *Current* towards values in array *A* with time 5 seconds. Since it's the first in queue, it starts to execute immediately. Before the fade is actually completed, I set time 20 seconds and press Button2. So I just added another fade in a queue list: from *Current* towards the values in array *B*. Since I'm changing the same values (index 0..20), this is starting to be executed right **after** the first fade completes. Note: the fading process is constantly updating the *Current* array, until it has the same values as the fade command's array! Therefore, the second fade will fade again from *Current* to *B*, with *Current* actually being same as *A*.

Now where things gets even more complicated is when I actually set just values indexed 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 from the arrays to be faded @5sec to *A*, and then I apply the values indexed 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 to be faded @10sec to *B* values: in that case, since the indexes I am fading are different ones, both fade commands should execute **right away**.

In case one value is in both fades (such as if I'd add value indexed 4 to the second fade), only this value would need to be added to a queue list. So the other fades right away, while the one that is already fading in the first fade, waits for it to finish, and then starts to fade as per the second command.

Some additional information:

- Lengths of the arrays are not fixed at the moment, but could be set fixed if this is important. It is for sure a multiplier of 512 with a maximum of 2047.
- The number of arrays is unknown and is to be modified in runtime as needed. They will probably be stored as records, (such as `StoredVals: array of record;`, `Index: array of Integer` (index of the values; this is to tell which values are stored in this record), and `Value: array of Byte;` (these are actual values that are faded, based on `Current[StoredVals[0].Index[0]]` for example. *Current* is keeping data of all values, meanwhile the records of *A*, *B*, *C* etc... keeps only the values of those which are indexed inside that record).
- The lengths of the arrays are, based on the description above, not always equal since they aren't always changing the same amount of values.
- The arrays are filled from the database at initialization. Since they can be created on runtime, they are filled from the *Current* values and stored as new array as well. But this is always also written in a database as well then. They are kind of memorized values, so that I can recall them with buttons. For that matter, I would like to have an option to recall those values immediately (as I do now already) or via the fading option. Now, to avoid the issues for a value in the queue, I was thinking of sending that *immediate* change through the fading process as well, only with time 0 seconds. That way, the values which are not in queue would be applied immediately, while if some value is currently fading, it will be applied after that fade is complete. That said, this fade process would be in the command flow all the time.

If there's any other extra clarification needed, please don't hesitate to ask!

I know this is really complicated, and that's why I'm looking for your help. Any partial help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What would be expected with concurrent fades e.g. S1 a>b 30 sec and 5 seconds later S2 a>c 10 sec, I would expect S1 would have to be terminated?

Comment: See [math for slow image zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11065801/757830) which provides the basics. Rewrite to your specifics.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm after a general function/procedure...

Actually, you seem to be after a complete program. You are thinking about solving it as a whole, and that's clouding, which is why you have so many questions. You need to learn breaking this task up in smaller parts, and to summarize the requirements more clearly. The question in its current form is close to being off-topic, and it probably would fit better at [SE Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). But since this fits right up my alley, I would like to step you through.

#### Requirements

- There is a set of values X of length N.
- One or more values in this set can be assigned a new value.
- The modification from an old value to the new value should be performed in steps within a specific duration.
- This results in intermediate values during this transition.
- This transition is value/index specific, i.e. the duration for X[0] could differ from that for X[1].
- A transition has to be entirely completed before another new value can be assigned.
- New values may be requested for assignment while a transition is in progress.
- This concludes that new requests should be stored in a queue, such that when a transition is completed, en new value request can be pulled from the queue resulting in a new transition.

I am pretty sure this is a correct summary of your question.

#### Transitions

Your proposal to use a Timer to perform a *piece* of the total transition on every interval is sound. Now, there are two ways to calculate those *pieces*:

1. Divide the total transition into a fixed number of small transitions, set the Timer's interval to the total duration divided by that number and handle the *sum of all processed smaller transitions* on every interval. This is what you propose in the calculation of the *change step*. The drawback with this method is a twofold:

   - A Timer's interval is an approximation and will not be exact because of various reasons, one of them being dependend on the Windows messaging model which' timing is affected by many processes, including yours,
   - A possible rough or unsmooth progress because of it.
2. Recalculate the *part of the processed transition* at every interval. That way the progress will always be smooth, whether the next interval takes two times more or not.

The second solution is preferred, and this translates into the following general routine you are looking for. Let's start simple by assuming a single item:

```
function InBetweenValue(BeginValue, EndValue: Byte; Duration, 
  StartTick: Cardinal): Byte
var
  Done: Single;
begin
  Done := (GetTickCount - StartTick) / Duration;
  if Done >= 1.0 then
    Result := EndValue
  else
    Result := Round(BeginValue + (EndValue - BeginValue) * Done);
end;
```

> Is using a Timer with fixed interval a good idea?

With this approach, the Timer's interval does *not* affect the calculation: at any given time the result of `InBetweenValue` will be correct. The *only* thing the Timer is needed for is driving the progress. If you want a 67 Hz refresh rate then set its interval to 15 milliseconds. If you want a refresh rate of 20 Hz, then set the interval to 50 milliseconds.

#### Performance

> Would it cause any delays if a lot of values would be pending for fade?

No, not for the implied reason. The time needed for all calculations may depend on the size of the queue, but that will for sure not be a significant factor. (If so, then you have problems of a much more troubling caliber). Possible "delays" will be manifested in a a lesser refresh rate due to missed or merged Windows Timer messages, depending on how busy the computer is with everything it's doing.

#### Data storage

> Is using dynamic arrays for values and times (and populating them on "StartFade" event and release them after fading is complete) a shot in the dark or a good guess?

Let's first analyze what data needs to be handled. There is a single set of in-between *current* values of arbitrary length, and each value has its own four attributes: begin value, end value, transition duration and transition start time. So you have the choice between:

1. Storing 5 sets: one set of current values and four sets of attributes, or
2. Storing 1 set: a single set of current values wherein each value has four attribute *members*.

The first solution requires trouble with keeping all five sets synchronized. The second requires another dimension. I would prefer the latter.

Whether you use arrays or something else is up to you. Choose what you are most comfortable with, what fits the purpose or what matches the input or required output best. Whether you choose static of dynamic arrays depends on the variability of the input and makes no measurable difference in performance. Dynamic arrays require runtime length management, where static arrays do not.

But since you need a dynamic solution anyway, then I suggest thinking outside the box. For example, the RTL offers no default built-in management tools for arrays, but it does have collection classes that do, e.g. `TList`.

For the rest of this answer, I will assume the decision of using an Object for an element and a List for keeping track of them.

#### Design

Now that the two most pressing points have been addressed, the design can be worked out.

There is a List with items, and each item has its current value and four attributes: begin, end, duration and start time. Each item must be capable of getting new attribute values. There is a formula for calculating the current value, based on the attributes. And there is a Timer which should automate a multiple of these calculations.

Furthermore, a multiple of transition *commands* should be stored for an Item. Since we have an Item with members already, let's add those commands as member of the Item too.

Something missing? No. Let's go.

#### Implementation

We need:

- A type for a Transition with two members: end value and duration,
- A type for a multiple of these transitions, preferably with queue characteristics,
- A type for an Item with six members: begin value, end value, duration, start time, current value and transitions,
- A type for a List of such Items,
- A routine for calculating the current value of an Item,
- A routine for popping up a new transition when the current value reached the end value,
- A routine for doing this calculation and popping on all Items,
- A Timer to drive this over-all routine,
- A routine for updating an Item's attributes. Recapitulate. Do we need the ability to set all the attributes? Doesn't a transition have all the settings needed?
- A type for an Object holding this all together.

This should help you set up the interface part of the code. Linger, and contain eagerness to start coding the implementation.

Hereby my try-out, originated as described above:

```
unit Modulation;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, WinAPI.Windows,
  VCL.ExtCtrls;

type
  TTransition = record
    EndValue: Byte;
    Duration: Cardinal;
  end;

  TTransitions = class(TQueue<TTransition>);

  TByte = class(TObject)
  private
    FBeginValue: Byte;
    FCurrentValue: Byte;
    FEndValue: Byte;
    FDuration: Cardinal;
    FStartTick: Cardinal;
    FTransitions: TTransitions;
    procedure PopTransition;
  public
    procedure AddTransition(ATransition: TTransition);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function HasTransition: Boolean;
    function InTransition: Boolean;
    procedure Recalculate;
    property CurrentValue: Byte read FCurrentValue;
  end;

  TBytes = class(TObjectList<TByte>);

  TByteModulator = class(TObject)
  private
    FItems: TBytes;
    FOnProgress: TNotifyEvent;
    FTimer: TTimer;
    function Finished: Boolean;
    function GetCurrentValue(Index: Integer): Byte;
    function GetItemCount: Integer;
    procedure SetItemCount(Value: Integer);
    procedure Proceed(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure DoProgress;
  public
    procedure AddTransition(Index: Integer; ATransition: TTransition);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property CurrentValues[Index: Integer]: Byte read GetCurrentValue; default;
    property ItemCount: Integer read GetItemCount write SetItemCount;
    property OnProgress: TNotifyEvent read FOnProgress write FOnProgress;
  end;

implementation

{ TByte }

procedure TByte.AddTransition(ATransition: TTransition);
begin
  if ATransition.Duration < 1 then
    ATransition.Duration := 1;
  FTransitions.Enqueue(ATransition);
  Recalculate;
end;

constructor TByte.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FTransitions := TTransitions.Create;
  FDuration := 1;
end;

destructor TByte.Destroy;
begin
  FTransitions.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TByte.HasTransition: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FTransitions.Count > 0;
end;

function TByte.InTransition: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FCurrentValue <> FEndValue;
end;

procedure TByte.PopTransition;
var
  Transition: TTransition;
begin
  Transition := FTransitions.Dequeue;
  FBeginValue := FCurrentValue;
  FEndValue := Transition.EndValue;
  FDuration := Transition.Duration;
  FStartTick := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure TByte.Recalculate;
var
  Done: Single;
begin
  Done := (GetTickCount - FStartTick) / FDuration;
  if Done >= 1.0 then
  begin
    FCurrentValue := FEndValue;
    if HasTransition then
      PopTransition;
  end
  else
    FCurrentValue := Round(FBeginValue + (FEndValue - FBeginValue) * Done);
end;

{ TByteModulator }

const
  RefreshFrequency = 25;

procedure TByteModulator.AddTransition(Index: Integer;
  ATransition: TTransition);
begin
  FItems[Index].AddTransition(ATransition);
  FTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

constructor TByteModulator.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FItems := TBytes.Create(True);
  FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  FTimer.Enabled := False;
  FTimer.Interval := MSecsPerSec div RefreshFrequency;
  FTimer.OnTimer := Proceed;
end;

destructor TByteModulator.Destroy;
begin
  FTimer.Free;
  FItems.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TByteModulator.DoProgress;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnProgress) then
    FOnProgress(Self);
end;

function TByteModulator.Finished: Boolean;
var
  Item: TByte;
begin
  Result := True;
  for Item in FItems do
    if Item.InTransition or Item.HasTransition then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
end;

function TByteModulator.GetCurrentValue(Index: Integer): Byte;
begin
  Result := FItems[Index].CurrentValue;
end;

function TByteModulator.GetItemCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FItems.Count;
end;

procedure TByteModulator.Proceed(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TByte;
begin
  for Item in FItems do
    Item.Recalculate;
  DoProgress;
  FTimer.Enabled := not Finished;
end;

procedure TByteModulator.SetItemCount(Value: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := FItems.Count to Value - 1 do
    FItems.Add(TByte.Create);
  FItems.DeleteRange(Value, FItems.Count - Value);
end;

end.
```

And a tiny plug-and-play demonstration program (note that the labels only show the last request):

[image]

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  VCL.ComCtrls, VCL.StdCtrls, Modulation;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    FBars: array of TProgressBar;
    FLabels: array of TLabel;
    FByteModulator: TByteModulator;
    procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Progress(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm2 }

const
  Count = 10;

constructor TForm2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FByteModulator := TByteModulator.Create;
  FByteModulator.ItemCount := Count;
  FByteModulator.OnProgress := Progress;
  SetLength(FBars, Count);
  SetLength(FLabels, Count);
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    FBars[I] := TProgressBar.Create(Self);
    FBars[I].SetBounds(10, 10 + 30 * I, 250, 25);
    FBars[I].Smooth := True;
    FBars[I].Max := High(Byte);
    FBars[I].Parent := Self;
    FLabels[I] := TLabel.Create(Self);
    FLabels[I].SetBounds(270, 15 + 30 * I, 50, 25);
    FLabels[I].Parent := Self;
  end;
  OnClick := FormClick;
end;

destructor TForm2.Destroy;
begin
  FByteModulator.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Transition: TTransition;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Transition.EndValue := Random(High(Byte) + 1);
  Transition.Duration := Random(3000);
  Index := Random(Count);
  FLabels[Index].Caption := Format('%d > %d @ %f',
    [FByteModulator.CurrentValues[Index], Transition.EndValue,
    Transition.Duration / MSecsPerSec]);
  FByteModulator.AddTransition(Index, Transition);
end;

procedure TForm2.Progress(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    FBars[I].Position := FByteModulator.CurrentValues[I];
end;

initialization
  Randomize;

end.
```

Succes.

Comment: Well, TBH, from my point of view it's not a whole program, but rather just a piece of code, coming from the fact that this is a piece of what I'm (trying to) create as a "Whole program";  However you just proved the opposite about the "piece of code" part, and this is indeed pretty big issue that you apparently, at least that's how it looks like from your example that I just compiled and run, managed to solve!
Now, just give me a day to come through your code and process all of it until understood, and I will come back again with either questions or simple "thank you" :)
But, so far, thanks!

Comment: a'right, this works just as I need actually. I did change a few things and parameters to suit my needs, but the point is that your core principle works for my needs! Thank you.

Do I have your permission to use this and, in case if needed in the future distribute this as part of my application? I'm happy to name you as contributor to the app of course!

Comment: Damn, you took some time to edit my question. Thanks, I guess...

Bdw, just a warning on your answer's code in Modulation unit: I don't think it is a really good idea to use TBytes for custom type, since it's reserved type in System.SysUtils...
It might get someone in a little trouble with incompatibility (like it did for me until I figured it was declared from Modulation instead of SysUtils...)   ;)

Comment: Naming is up to you. As long as `Modulation` is placed after `SysUtils` in a uses clause, then `TBytes` refers to `Modulation.TBytes`. Anyway, both can be distinguished by qualifying namespace: `(System.)SysUtils.TBytes` and `Modulation.TBytes`. It should not give more problems than wanting `Graphics.TBitmap` instead of `Windows.TBitmap` e.g.

Comment: Just a small sidenote question; I can't seem to find/edit where you take the beginvalue from... If it's not too much to ask, could you explain how to re-edit it, so that it's taking the values for each item from the array of byte (using same index) ? Thank you!

Comment: If I'm correct, just please confirm on me -> Is this to be set in PopTransition procedure at FBeginValue? It seems to, but am not sure since I can't get complete drawback on the procedure..

Comment: The initial value of each byte is 0. When you add a single transition of _9 @0msec_, then that byte instantly has value 9. If you want to apply multiple new values (your array _A_, _B_, _C_...) to multiple bytes, then call `AddTransition` for every index. You can add a routine doing so yourself, within or outside this class. In my answer I "forgot" to mention that you could realize that it doesn't matter where a value or more values come from. Whether from _A_, _B_, of from _K_, you simply have to add a transition to every single item eventually, regardless the implementation.

Comment: Yes, `PopTransition` is the only place where `FBeginValue` is being assigned.

Comment: I actually fixed the ItemCount to 512, so that I have 512 items representing 512 values, and therefore add transitions to the specific item based on the index of the value I want to fade. This way, it all seems a bit clearer to me... :)  I was just missing the BeginValue, but it looks like PopTransition is the place to edit and have it working as it should ( I hope).
I'll see. :)